# jQuery Re-Binding after tab change using Active Social for DotNetNuke

Tags: jquery, ajax, dotnetnuke

I am working with a third party tab control which is part of a DotNetnuke module called Active Social which I have no documentation for. The problem is when I change tabs I lose a js (masonry.js) which styles the content being loaded in the tab. I need to re-bind the script but have not been successful

Here is what I have so far.

I am using a re-binding method that I have used in previous projects

```
function BindControlEvents() {
        //jQuery is wrapped in BindEvents function so it can be re-bound after each callback.
        var $container = $('.addMasonry');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
            $container.masonry({
                itemSelector: '.explore-image',
                columnWidth: 10,
                isFitWidth: true
            });

        });

    }
    //Initial bind
    $(document).ready(function () {
        BindControlEvents();
    });
```

//        Re-bind for callbacks
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

```
    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        BindControlEvents();
    });
```

This however does not re-bind when the tab is changed. So I created a button on the page

```
 <li><a onclick="BindControlEvents();" href="#">re-bind</a></li>
```

Clicking this button after the tab change will re bind my script.

The next step I assume would be to find the event that tells me a tab is finished loading but so far I have been unsuccessful

I have tried selecting the tab container and running the BindControlEvents function on .load() and .ajaxComplete() but still no success.

Are there any other ways to find out when a tab is fully loaded. I understand I might not be giving much to work off of but this is as much as I know.

Thanks for the help

Mark

Comment: Without knowing what you are using for the tab control we can't really help you since we wont know how to investigate a way to know when the tab is loaded. Could you switch to using jQuery UI Tabs?

Comment: I though this would make it tough. I can not really switch as the tabs are a core part of a DotNetNuke module called Active Social. Maybe I should add this to the question in hope someone here has gone through the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a partial postback that is not intercepted, try to add the following in your js, outside of jquery init:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.Application.add_load(BindControlEvents);

    function BindControlEvents() {
    [...]
    </script>
```

Hope this helps,
al.